# knockout mapping with Requires Js

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

I've got the following fragment as part of my requireJs config.

```
paths: {
            // Folders
            "templates": 'templates',
            "static": "static",
            "commonRequireJsModules": "commonRequireJsModules",
            "text": "commonRequireJsModules/text",
            "packages": 'packages',
            "contextSheets": "contextsheets",

            //Plugins
            "jquery": "./jquery-1.8.3",
            'jqueryUI': './jquery-ui-1.10.0.custom.min',
            "jqx": "/Content/Plugins/jqWidgets",
            'signalR': './jquery.signalR-1.0.1',
            'knockout': './knockout-2.1.0',
            'komapping': './knockout.mapping-latest.debug',
```

I can see in the network tab of chrome that the mapping plugin is being loaded but for some reason I never get a ref to it in my module.

```
define(
[
    'knockout',
    'komapping',
    'text!templates/productImages-ko.txt',
    'commonRequireJsModules/debugConsole'

],
function (ko, mapping , koTemplate, debugConsole) {
```

ko is loaded but the mapping param is always undef. Any ideas I'm using 2.4.1 of the mapping plugin.

Thx.

Comment: I've just updated to 2.2.1 of knockout to see if it made a difference, sadly same issue.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code you posted at first glance. I did notice that your quotes are sometimes single and sometimes double, which makes me think you're pulling in code from different projects...check your quotes and commas to make sure they all line up.

Comment: Yeah cheers, multiple devs working on the project. It alls hooks up fine as the other 3 params are all correctly loaded it's just the mapping plugin that has the issue.

Comment: I'd try switching to the non-debug version of the plugin.  Could be an issue with your mapping plugin file.  My next guess would be a compatibility issue with another plugin, but I don't know of any compatibility issues with ko.mapping.